# Unable to display anything through Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to build a highlighting library with JavaScript and jQuery. I am just diving into Canvasing techniques this week and did not find them to be all that difficult. However, while working today my code has simply stopped working. I know I am probably just missing something obvious but I have been stuck like this for almost 2 hours now and I need to get this project moving forward again. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {
  $('area').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d").fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d").fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
  } );
} );
```

I have included my Javascript only since that is the only thing I have been changing recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, assuming:

- The page has a clickable `area`.
- The page has a canvas with an #id of `ctx`.

Make sure those 2 things are true about your setup...

Does your canvas element have an #id of `ctx`? That's not fatal, but the canvas element contains a `context` so it's a bit misleading.

If you have a canvas element like this:

```
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```

Then you can get a reusable reference to the canvas's context like this:

```
// no need to constantly get a context reference ...
//     just do it once at the start of your app
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var context=canvas.getContext('2d');
```

And you can reuse that context reference to do all your drawing calls:

```
context.fillStyle='red';
context.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
```

Comment: You were right on the money with the ID, I had forgotten I changed it and never updated my styling or references. Thank you for the insight, I am clearly standing on my last legs today haha!

Comment: Glad to help! :-)